# Excel vsto addin not being fully loaded by some computers

Tags: excel, vsto

I’ve been dealing with this for a week and have viewed all related posts I can find on the web.

I’ve developed a vsto excel addin that I’m trying to distribute to alpha users for testing. I’ve done this successfully with 4 users on both windows 8.1 and 10 using both excel 32 and 64 bit. A fifth user, on windows 10 Excel 32,  cannot run it. The following is the process:
•   Publish from VS2019
•   Put on website for downloading
•   User downloads and unblocks the zip in a specific C: directory
•   Extracts all from download
•   Double clicks setup.exe in the extract directory
•   For the successful testers all is good. The addin is loaded, appears in the ribbon and runs just fine.

The unsuccessful tester ends up with the following
•   Addin appears in apps
•   Addin appears in Registry with status 3 and the correct path to the vsto file
•   Addin   DOES NOT appear in Excel Com addins.
•   Addin DOES NOT  appear in disabled addins
•   Double clicking vsto file does not fix this
•   Adding the path to trusted locations does nothing.
•   I’ve put a trace in the addin start up that never executes (it does on the other installations).

Any insight or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### The add-in has been hard disabled

So, how do I re-enable a hard disabled add-in?

```
In the Manage box, change COM Add-ins to Disabled Add-ins, and then click Go.
Select the add-in and click Enable. Click Close.
```

OK, now the add-in can be loaded again:

```
In the Manage box, change Disabled Add-ins to COM Add-ins, and then click Go.
select the check box next to the disabled add-in. Click OK.
```

Reference: [MSDN_Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but as I said above it is not appearing in the disabled list